# Failed to execute 'createOffer' on 'RTCPeerConnection': 2 arguments required, but only 0 present

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

```
var peerConnectionConfig = {'iceServers': [{'url': 'stun:stun.services.mozilla.com'}, {'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}]};
window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
var peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(peerConnectionConfig);
var promise = peerConnection.createOffer();
```

I'm trying to create an offer with PeerConnection as shown [in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/createOffer) but I'm getting the following error in Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createOffer' on 'RTCPeerConnection': 2 arguments required, but only 0 present.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is because chrome does not return a promise, it expects a success and error callbacks functions as parameters, you can circumvent these differences and avoid manually handling prefix differences by using [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter)

Comment: Works in Chrome Canary now, but +1 on adapter.js nonetheless.